# Tensorflow in Android: java.nio.BufferOverFlowException

Tags: java, android, tensorflow

Good morning. I'm a developer trying to put a tensorflow model into Android.
I've encountered an error that I've never seen before while trying to fix it with multiple errors.
The `java.nio.BufferOverFlowException` error i'm facing now is that it didn't happen before, but it happened suddenly.
My code uses a byte array, but i cannot specify which part is the problem.

This source that takes a float array as input and returns an array with 10 classes after passing through the model.
The returned values have softmax value.

```
public float[] hypothesis(float[] inputFloats, int nFeatures, int nClasses, Context context)
{
    try {
        int nInstance = inputFloats.length / nFeatures;
       // FloatBuffer.wrap(inputFloats);
        Toast.makeText(context, "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        inferenceInterface.feed(INPUT_NODE, FloatBuffer.wrap(inputFloats), INPUT_SIZE);
        inferenceInterface.run(OUTPUT_NODES_HYPO);
        float[] result = new float[nInstance * nClasses];
        inferenceInterface.fetch(OUTPUT_NODE_HYPO, result);
        return result;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(context, e+" ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return null;
    }
}
```

The length of the `inputfloats` is 720 and the `nFeatures` is 720. `nClasses` is 10.
Although the value is not correct, it worked before. 
e in the catch statement prints `java.nio.BufferOverFlowException`.

Could there be a problem in the middle of converting a byte array to a float array?
Related source.

```
public float[] bytetofloat(byte[] array){
    int[] returnArr = new int[array.length/4];
    float[] returnArr1 = new float[array.length/4];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < returnArr.length; i++){
        //array[i] = 0;
        returnArr[i] = array[i*4] & 0xFF;
        if(returnArr[i] < 0 || returnArr[i]>255)
            Log.d("ARRAY", returnArr[i]+" ");
        returnArr1[i] = (float)returnArr[i];
    }
    return returnArr1;
}
```

---

```
 public Bitmap RGB2GRAY(Bitmap image){
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();
    Bitmap bmOut;
    bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
    for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){
        for(int y = 0 ; y < height; y++){
            int pixel = image.getPixel(x, y);
            int A = Color.alpha(pixel);
            int R = Color.red(pixel);
            int G = Color.green(pixel);
            int B = Color.blue(pixel);
            R = G = B = (int)(0.2126 * R + 0.7152 * G + 0.0722 * B);
            bmOut.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(A, R, G, B));

        }
    }
    return bmOut;
}

private void activityPrediction(float[] inputArray){
    try {

        float[] result = activityInference.hypothesis(inputArray, 20*36, 10, getApplicationContext());
        predictionView.setText(Arrays.toString(result));
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}
```

---

```
 private byte[] bitmapToByteArray(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    int chunkNumbers = 10;
    int bitmapSize = bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
    byte[] imageBytes = new byte[bitmapSize];
    int rows, cols;
    int chunkHeight, chunkWidth;
    rows = cols = (int) Math.sqrt(chunkNumbers);
    chunkHeight = bitmap.getHeight() / rows;
    chunkWidth = bitmap.getWidth() / cols;

    int yCoord = 0;
    int bitmapsSizes = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++)
    {
        int xCoord = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < cols; y++)
        {
            Bitmap bitmapChunk = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, xCoord, yCoord, chunkWidth, chunkHeight);
            byte[] bitmapArray = getBytesFromBitmapChunk(bitmapChunk);
            System.arraycopy(bitmapArray, 0, imageBytes, bitmapsSizes, bitmapArray.length);
            bitmapsSizes = bitmapsSizes + bitmapArray.length;
            xCoord += chunkWidth;

            bitmapChunk.recycle();
            bitmapChunk = null;
        }
        yCoord += chunkHeight;
    }

    return imageBytes;
}
private byte[] getBytesFromBitmapChunk(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    int bitmapSize = bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bitmapSize);
    bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer);
    byteBuffer.rewind();
    return byteBuffer.array();
}
```

'e.printStackTrace()' result

```
at com.example.leehanbeen.platerecognize.ActivityInference.hypothesis(ActivityInference.java:58)
    at com.example.leehanbeen.platerecognize.MainActivity.activityPrediction(MainActivity.java:148)
    at com.example.leehanbeen.platerecognize.MainActivity.access$100(MainActivity.java:28)
    at com.example.leehanbeen.platerecognize.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:69)
```

around MainActivity.java:69

```
byte[] byteArrayRes = bitmapToByteArray(image_bitmap);
float[] inputArray = bytetofloat(byteArrayRes);

activityPrediction(inputArray);
```

MainActivity.java:28

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

MainActivity.java:148

```
float[] result = activityInference.hypothesis(inputArray, 20*36, 10, getApplicationContext());
```

around ActivityInference.java:58

```
float[] result = new float[nInstance * nClasses];
inferenceInterface.fetch(OUTPUT_NODE_HYPO, result);
```

Comment: Can you obtain the stacktrace?

Comment: i included stacktrace :)

Comment: Looks like the problem is related to input image resolution. This link might be useful: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12649

Comment: thx I will try this